# ring theory questions... what is a subring?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

So I've got coursework to do, and having not been to some (most) lectures, I'm at that time where it's time to learn everything I need to know... Any help is much appreicated, thanks!

I've been given 2 rings, and a subset S, and I have to determine whether or not S is a subring of the rings, giving a reason/explanation as to why not, or a proof if it indeed is.

First of all, can someone as simply as possible explain the difference between a Ring, a Set, and a Group... My understanding is that a set is just a collection of elements. A group is a collection of elements together with a binary function (not entirely sure what a binary funtion is...) that obeys the group axioms (which I think I understand). Not sure what a Ring is...

So what is a subring? And how does one prove a set is a subring of any ring R..?

Thanks, Doug

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation) for binary function, and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subring) for subring.

Answer (score 1):

A set, is as you said, just collection of elements. It's not that simple as there are axioms to define a set, but for the time being, assuming it's a collection of subjects is "ok".

A group $G$ is a set with an operation $\cdot : G^2\to G$, that is it assigns to each pair of elements $a,b$ in $G$ an element $a\cdot b$ that also belongs to $G$. The group axioms are that this operation, called multiplication is associativity, the existence of an identity element $1$ such that $1\cdot e=e\cdot1=e$ for all $e\in G$., and the existence of the inverse element $e^{-1}$ such that $e\cdot e^{-1}=e^{-1}\cdot e=1$ for each $e$ in $G$.

An abelian group is a group in which $a\cdot b=b\cdot a$.

Now, for the ring. The ring is a set with two operations, addition and multiplication. It acts as an abelian group under addition, that is, the addition operation satisfies all the axioms given above. The identity element for addition is called $0$.

However, under the operation called multiplication, it's different.  The only axioms it needs to satisfy are that it assigns values into the ring itself (closure), that it is associative, and that it distributes over addition. That is, $a\cdot(b+c)=a\cdot b+a\cdot c$ and $(a+b)\cdot c=a\cdot c+b\cdot c$.

Now, if a ring has the identity $1$ element for multiplication, it's called a ring with identity. If the multiplication operation is commutative, it's called a commutative ring.

As for the subring, it's a subset of the ring such that this subset acts as a ring in itself.

Since the operations have the same properties in the subset, I think all you have to do is prove closure for both operations, as well as the existence of the $0$ element and the existence of the additive inverse for each element in the subset. I might have made a mistake as I'm not experienced with the subject, and since I'm in a hurry, so do excuse any mistakes. I hope this helps.

Comment: What would be an example of a non-abelian group? I can't think of two elements a,b such that a.b doesn't equal b.a

Comment: and I don't quite understand what you mean by 'if the multiplication operation is commutative?

Comment: @Douglas A very basic example of a non-abelian group is the matrix group. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_group 
As you can see, multiplication maps into the group, the identity matrix represents the multiplicative identity, every matrix in that group has an inverse, so it's a group. However, $AB$ is generally different from $BA$. This is an example.

And what I meant is that if $a\cdot b=b\cdot a$ then it is called commutative ring. Remember, in a ring, we have $a+b=b+a$ but not necessarily $a\cdot b=b\cdot a$. I hope I didn't make any mistakes and that the idea reaches you well.